# JBoss: fatal boot error

Tags: jboss

For some reason I can not deploy on my jboss server any more, I meet exception:

```
17:53:41,244 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "my.ear")]) - failure description: "JBAS018717: No deployment content with hash eee1ea03abae2b5f61718c00189c0ec40bf914a0 is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'my.ear'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart."
17:53:41,250 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

I cannot undeploy it from `cli`:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=localhost:my_port
[standalone@localhost:my_port /] undeploy my.ear
Undeploy failed: {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014807: Management resource '[(\"deployment\" => \"my.ear\")]' not found"}}
```

Help me please figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens when cli has a reference to an application it can no longer find.

Perhaps you deleted your data directory inside standalone folder?

To fix the problem, you can edit your standalone.xml file (or whatever version you are using) and look for the deployments element, and delete the deployment element that fails, and try to deploy again

For example

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="my.ear" runtime-name="my.ear">
        <content sha1="xxxxxxx"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Arquillian didn't clear it after test because I killed process

Comment: It happens too if you deploy an application using JBoss Console then delete it directly from /deployments directory of the server. Thank you for this useful answer this helped me.